# Drawable Image does not scale as per screen density

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I have an ImageView that is a part of ListItemView that is suppose to be displayed in the ListView. Without the Image, each item of listview takes less height. This is consistent across all the screens as they all are of same height. However, in one of the activities, I need to display an image in the listview items and this always increases the size of each item for that activity. I have the proper folder structure under res > drawable > family > family (hdpi), family (mdpi), family (xhdpi), family (xxhdpi), fmaily (xxxhdpi)

So each image has 5 version based upon the screen density.

I have the below in my layout file:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"/>
```

and I am setting the image in Java code:

```
ImageView imageView = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageResource(word.getImage());
```

However, no matter what resolution I choose, the image size always seems to be the same and it affects the size of the whole ListItemView in the ListView.

Size of ListView item without image:

[image: Without ImageView]

With ImageView:

[image]

You may have noticed the change in the height of the ListView item with gray background. Is this normal. I dont want to fix the size of the image. I would like to scale it based upon screen resolution, however, it should not distort the overall height of the ListView item. This image remains the same no matter what the screen density is. why won't it scale automatically and fit the ListView item.

Is this normal or is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allowing the Image to decide how much space it can use by setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and then having the width scale accordingly (in order for your `layout_weight` to work properly).

You could change your layout to force the `ImageView` to the height you prefer and let the use the `scaleType`to get the preferred scaling. In this example I used `fitCenter` but there are others that can be chosen (eg. `fitXY`).

By using the size qualifier `dp` the image will automatically "scale" with screen density as `dp` is Density-independent Pixels which means it will change with the screen density.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"/>
```